# how to check if lines are parallel using the transform image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a theoretical question:
If I have an image with lines that seems to be parallel, and I need to check if they are so using the transform image of that image, how can I do it?
how can I tell from the transform image if they are parallel?

Answer (score 4):

Use the Hough transform.

In the Hough result "image" every straight line is a dot. On one axis you have the angle of each line in the image, on the other you have each line's crossing with one of the axis.

To check if your lines are parallel detect the two dots and see if they have the same angle value.

Regards

Comment: tnx a lot! exactly what i needed